# Updating state array based on another array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update an array based on another array. For example, if Array 2 contains the word "Fully Furnished", I would like to update Array1 Fully Furnished 'checked' to true.

```
const [Array1,
        setArray1] = useState([
            {
                checked: false,
                title: "Fully Furnished"
            }, {
                checked: false,
                title: "Swimming Pool"
            }, {
                checked: false,
                title: "En suite Rooms"
            }
        ]);

const Array2= ["Fully Furnished", "Swimming Pool"];
```

This is what I have been trying so far, but it only updates the first row.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < Array2.length; i++) {
            setArray1(
                Array1.map((item, i) =>
                    item.title === Array2[i] && item.checked === false
                        ? { ...item, checked: true }
                        : item
                ))
        }
    }, []);
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const array3=Array1.map(function (item) {
    if (Array2.includes(item.title)) {
        item.checked = true;
    }
    return item;
})
setArray1(array3)
```

You may try this inside useEffect function.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to polish up on your algorithm skills

```js
const list1 = [{
  checked: false,
  title: "Fully Furnished"
}, {
  checked: false,
  title: "Swimming Pool"
}, {
  checked: false,
  title: "En suite Rooms"
}];

const list2 = ["Fully Furnished", "Swimming Pool"];

list2.forEach((item => {

  let index = list1.findIndex(looky => looky.title == item);

  if (index != undefined) {
    list1[index].checked = true;
  }
}));

console.log(list1);
```